# Getting concurrent modification exception on multi threaded merge

Tags: java, multithreading

Basically I have this code that is using multiple threads to execute a merge sort algorithm I hope to scale this up to N given threads but currently I'm just trying to get four to work. Basically I create four different threads and pass each of them a subarray of the whole. After they've executed I have 4 different sorted sub-arrays that I then need to merge. Because I'm not really sure how to close threads and clear those resources entirely I am trying to reuse two of those threads to absorb a given array into their internal arrays and then re-run the thread with a boolean which tells the thread to merge the two halves rather than sort everything again. This seems to work the first time when I try with merger 0, and merger 1, but then when I try to do the same thing with 2 and three I get a concurrent modification exception. Now I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong and if anyone has suggestions on how I could improve this code or reduce the number of array creations and copies that would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecursiveSimples {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Comparable> nums = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
        nums.add(7); nums.add(4);
        nums.add(8); nums.add(6);
        nums.add(1); nums.add(3);
        nums.add(4); nums.add(7);
        nums.add(2); nums.add(1);
        nums.add(5); nums.add(9);
        nums.add(8); nums.add(3);
        nums.add(2); nums.add(2);

        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        int r = nums.size() % 4;
        int num = nums.size() / 4;

        List<Merger> mergers = new ArrayList<Merger>();
        mergers.add(new Merger(nums.subList(0, num))); 
        mergers.add(new Merger(nums.subList(num, num*2)));
        mergers.add(new Merger(nums.subList(num*2, num*3))); 
        mergers.add(new Merger(nums.subList(num*3, (num*4) +r)));

        mergers.get(0).start(); mergers.get(1).start();
        mergers.get(2).start(); mergers.get(3).start();

        mergers.get(0).join(); mergers.get(1).join();
        mergers.get(2).join(); mergers.get(3).join();

        System.out.println(mergers.get(0).getNums());
        System.out.println(mergers.get(1).getNums());
        System.out.println(mergers.get(2).getNums());
        System.out.println(mergers.get(3).getNums());

        mergers.get(0).absorbList(mergers.get(1).getNums());
        mergers.get(0).setMerger(true);
        mergers.get(0).run();
        System.out.println(mergers.get(0).getNums());

        mergers.get(2).absorbList(mergers.get(3).getNums());
        mergers.get(2).setMerger(true);
        mergers.get(2).run();

        System.out.println(mergers.get(1).getNums());
        System.out.println(mergers.get(3).getNums());

        int maxThreads = nums.size() / 2;



    }
}


class Merger extends Thread {
    private List<Comparable> nums;
    private boolean merge = false;

    public List<Comparable> getNums() {
        return nums;
    }

    public void setMerger(boolean bool) {
        merge = bool;
    }

    public void absorbList(List<Comparable>  list) {
        nums.addAll(list);
    }

    Merger(List<Comparable> arr) {
        nums = arr;
    }

    public void run() {
        if(merge == false) {
            mergeSort(nums, 0, nums.size() -1);
        }else {
            merge(nums, 0, (nums.size() -1)/2, nums.size() -1);
        }
    }

    public static void swap(List<Comparable> nums, int index1, int index2)
    {
        Comparable temp;
        temp = nums.get(index1);
        nums.set(index1, nums.get(index2));
        nums.set(index2, temp);
    }

    private static void mergeSort(List<Comparable> nums, int first, int last) {
         if (first < last)
            {
                int m = (first+last)/2;

                mergeSort(nums, first, m);
                mergeSort(nums, m+1, last);

                merge(nums, first, m, last);
            }
    }

    private static void merge(List<Comparable> nums, int first, int mid, int last){
         List<Comparable> newList = new  ArrayList<Comparable>();

         int loopCountA = 0;
         int loopCountB = 0;
         while(true) {
             if(loopCountB == (last - mid)) {
                 while(first + loopCountA <= mid) {
                     newList.add(nums.get(first + loopCountA)); loopCountA++;
                 }
                 break;
             }else if(first + loopCountA > mid) {
                 while(loopCountB < (last - mid)) {
                     newList.add(nums.get(mid + (loopCountB + 1))); loopCountB++;
                 }
                 break;
             }else {
                 if(nums.get(mid + (loopCountB + 1)).compareTo(nums.get(first + loopCountA)) < 0) {
                     newList.add(nums.get(mid + (loopCountB + 1)));
                     loopCountB++;
                 }else {
                     newList.add(nums.get(first + loopCountA));
                     loopCountA++;
                 }
             }
         }       

         for(int i = 0; (i - 1) < (last - first); i++)
             nums.set(first + i, newList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Merger is not part of JDK and we don't have it. Maybe you can share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the problem here (causing the exception) is the way you create sublists - you are using `subList(...)` method, but it doesn't create another list, just a view for existing one. When you process these different views of **one** list in different threads you are causing the exception (as every thread changes the same list).

Possible solution would be to change the method to create a sub list or modify constructor to keep a copy, e.g.:

```
Merger(List<Comparable> arr) {
    nums = new ArrayList<>(arr);
}
```